# Using Java Runtime class to find out a class in Jar file in Unix

Tags: java, unix

I am using Java Runtime class to write a program that checks for a class file in a list of jar files. Here is my program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find /home/user/lib/ -name \"*.jar\" | xargs grep MyClass.class");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception..");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program then I am getting error message as:

```
Here is the standard output of the command:

Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

**find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]**
```

Please help me what I am missing in this code, if I directly run the command `find /home/user/lib/ -name \"*.jar\" | xargs grep MyClass.class");` on my unix command line then it is working fine.

Also, if I replace the expression with below line then my Java code is working fine.

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/user/lib/ && find . -name \"*.jar\" | xargs grep MyClass.class" });
```

Comment: Guess only: the `*` gets expanded in the user's shell.

Comment: Thanks Joop, if I use the second expression mentioned in my post (it also has `*`) then program is working fine. So it seems I am missing something in my first expression.

Comment: Actually... why don't you just use a find + -exec where the executed program is jar tf {} | grep <class>? You won't need a Java program...

Answer (score 1):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find /home/user/lib/ -name \"*.jar");
```

Change that to

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c find /home/user/lib/ -name \"*.jar");
```

so that the shell gets involved and expands the wildcard.

But you don't really need to run `find` here, you could do it yourself with `Files.listFiles()` called recursively.

I'd be interested to see what you're doing next as well. I would do it by defining a `URLClassLoader` initialized with that list of JARs and then using it to try to load the class, rather than unzipping all the JARs myself.

Comment: But in this kind of find the wildcard '*' must not be expanded by the shell: find uses it to match all files below the target directory!

Comment: "interested...next" I'd just add an -exec to find with "jar tf {}" and pipe it into grep for the desired class. Why program if it's all there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*If* all jars are on the class path:

```
    Class<?> klazz = Class.forName("sun.security.ec.SunEC", false,
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    CodeSource codeSource = klazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    URL url = codeSource.getLocation();
    System.out.println(url.toExternalForm());

file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunec.jar
```

The detail to attend: `false` means no class initialisation to take place.

*Otherwise* with just a list of files, one might use JarFile. In Java 8 you might even use parallelism.